# how to fix this error?

Tags: asp.net, sql

HI i am try to do Implementing database record in treeview like Parent and Child(table).  During run time i got error in my connection string..

error line:-

```
string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=ASDF;Initial Catalog=dbtree;Integrated Security=True"].ConnectionString;
```

Error is :-

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Note:-in my database no fields are null

code:-

```
string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=ASDF;Initial Catalog=dbtree;Integrated Security=True"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
mycon.Open();
SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_Parent", mycon);
SqlDataReader dr = mycmd.ExecuteReader();
mycmd.Dispose();
string[,] ParentNode = new string[100, 2];
int count = 0;
while (dr.Read())
{
    ParentNode[count, 0] = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("Parent_id")).ToString();
    ParentNode[count++, 1] = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("Parent_name")).ToString();
}
dr.Close();
```

Comment: You are tyring to index an array using a string as the key, and there is no object there.  This has nothing to do with database fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection string line is not right.  It is looking for a node in web.config named

```
"Data Source=ASDF;Initial Catalog=dbtree;Integrated Security=True".
```

Since that node (apparently) doesn't exist, it is returning `null` and you are getting an exception.

I suspect you just want:

```
string connectionstring = "Data Source=ASDF;Initial Catalog=dbtree;Integrated Security=True";
```

But without more context I can't know for sure.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=ASDF;Initial Catalog=dbtree;Integrated Security=True"].ConnectionString;
```

With

```
string connectionstring = "Data Source=ASDF;Initial Catalog=dbtree;Integrated Security=True";
```

Or use connection string name

```
string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Name here"].ConnectionString;
```

Update: As commenter suggested below, you can find the name of a connection string in web.config file.